# How to cast Int to unsigned short in Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift

I have the following function from the Objective-C library in Swift project:

```
- (DDHotKey *)registerHotKeyWithKeyCode:(unsigned short)keyCode modifierFlags:(NSUInteger)flags task:(DDHotKeyTask)task {
    // ...
}
```

I'm trying to call this function from Swift via the following code:

```
    hotKeyCenter.registerHotKeyWithKeyCode(
        kVK_ANSI_V,
        modifierFlags: NSEventModifierFlags.ControlKeyMask.rawValue,
        task: { _ in
            // ...
        }
    )
```

Unfortunately, it gives me the following error:

> Missing argument for parameter 'action' in call

However, if I change `kVK_ANSI_V` to any number like this

```
    hotKeyCenter.registerHotKeyWithKeyCode(
        34,
        modifierFlags: NSEventModifierFlags.ControlKeyMask.rawValue,
        task: { _ in
            // ...
        }
    )
```

code compiles without any error.

As you know, `kVK_ANSI_V` defined in the Carbon framework:

```
var kVK_ANSI_V: Int { get }
```

As you see, it has an `Int` type while `keyCode` parameter of the method has an `unsigned short` type.

How can I cast `Int` to `unsigned short`? Is there any way to fix this error?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you tried casting to UInt ? i.e. UInt(kVK_ANSI_V)?

Comment: @giorashc Unfortunately, it doesn't work -- same error

Comment: unsigned short in objc is 2 bytes in size, so maybe UInt16 will work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an `UInt16` from any integer `n` simply
with `UInt16(n)`. In your case:

```
hotKeyCenter.registerHotKeyWithKeyCode(
    UInt16(kVK_ANSI_V),
    modifierFlags: NSEventModifierFlags.ControlKeyMask.rawValue,
    task: { _ -> Void in

})
```